# How to remove a row using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried to remove the third row

THIS IS THE EDIT I made based on the comments of rgettman, Leo, zibi. Thank you.

```
public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream file  =   new FileInputStream(new  File("test.xlsx") );
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(3));
//      sheet.shiftRows(3, 3, -1);

        File outWB = new File("testResult.xlsx");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outWB);
        wb.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();


        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

But this deletes values in a row but does not remove the row

Comment: I hope excel is not expecting a xlsx file

Comment: You are shifting row 3 down by 1.  Use negative numbers to shift up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are working with XLS files (not XLSX) then you should use HSSFWorkbook. I just tested the solution below and everything works fine:

```
    File file = new File(....);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    sheet.shiftRows(3, 3, -1);

    File outWB = new File(.....);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outWB);
    wb.write(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

or even beter use the Workbook factory, which does type recognizing for you:

```
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    sheet.shiftRows(3, 3, -1);
```

belowe you can find a function which does the row removal, it could be used both in xls and xlsx (tested;)).

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
removeRow(sheet, 2);
File outWB = new File(...);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outWB);
wb.write(out);
out.flush();
out.close();


public static void removeRow(Sheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum) {
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
        Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (removingRow != null) {
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. This works awesome . However i am using `xlsx ` . Could you please modify your answer to `xlsx ` Thank you.

Comment: It deletes all values in a row , but does not remove the row. I have posted an update

Comment: There is a bug in Apache 4.0.1 preventing this to work see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62711

Comment: It was discussed here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252684/how-to-delete-an-entire-row-from-excel-using-java-apache-poi

Answer (score 1):

**See the defnition of Shift rows:**

`Shifts rows between startRow and endRow n number of rows. If you use a negative number, it will shift rows up. Code ensures that rows don't wrap around. Calls shiftRows(startRow, endRow, n, false, false);`
`Additionally shifts merged regions that are completely defined in these rows (ie. merged 2 cells on a row to be shifted).`

```
Specified by: shiftRows(...) in Sheet
Parameters:
    startRow the row to start shifting
    endRow the row to end shifting
    n the number of rows to shift
```

So in order to remove the 3rd row you need to use `startRow = 3` (zero based indexing so basically it is fourth row), `endRow = sheet.getLastRowNum()` and `n = -1` to shift selected rows i.e. from 4th to the last row by 1 row upward.

Answer (score 1):

When I used the following instead of erasing single rows I was able to speed up deleting 200 from about 300 rows from 4s to 0,4s:

```
    for (Sheet currentSheet: workbook) {                
        RowDeleter rowDeleter = new RowDeleter(currentSheet);
       ...
        if (..) rowDeleter.removeRow(i);
       ...
       rowDeleter.execute();
    }

static class RowDeleter {
    private final Sheet sheet;
    private final boolean[] deleted;

    public RowDeleter(Sheet sheet) {
        this.sheet = sheet;
        deleted = new boolean[sheet.getLastRowNum()+1];
        Arrays.fill(deleted, false);
    }
    
    public void removeRow(int rowIndex) {
        deleted[rowIndex] = true;
    }
    
    public void execute() {
        int first = -1;
        int last = -1;
        for (int i = deleted.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if (deleted[i]) {
                first = i;
                if (last < 0) {
                    last = i;
                }
            } else if (first >= 0) {
                removeRows(first, last-first+1); 
                first = -1;
                last = -1;
            }
        }
        
    }
    void removeRows(int rowIndex, int count) {
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum) {
            sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + count, lastRowNum, -count);
        }
        if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
            Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if (removingRow != null) {
                sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try better special function [removeRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#removeRow%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row%29)

Also, XSSFWorkbook work with .xlsx extension.

Answer (score 0):

As I see RowDeleter from previous answer has cumulative effect (count of shifted rows constantly increasing). It works slower and slower. If shifting is started from beginning we don't need to move previous shifted records each time.
Note: I used several loops with different conditions to remove rows before shifting (to have sheet.getRow(i) == null, it takes seconds). lst+1 needed to trigger last shifting. It works much faster for me then previous (14k rows - 12 mins vs 1k rows - 10 mins), but anyway is not fast enough. I also recommend to remove formula dependencies, because it slows process and may cause workbook formula errors on opening in Excel. Here is my experiment:

```
    int lst = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int begining = -1;
    int ending = -1;
    int removed = 0;
    for (int i = 9; i <= lst+1; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (row == null) {
            if (begining > 0 && removed < 0) {
                System.out.println(begining +"_"+ ending);
                sheet.shiftRows(begining, ending, removed);
                begining = -1;
                ending = -1;
            }
            removed--;
        } else {
            if (removed < 0) {
                if (begining < 0) {
                    begining = i;
                }
                ending = i;
            }
        }
    }
```