# Edit or add a new row in excel file using apache POI

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi

I know how to write data in to a row in excel android. But how can I add a new row on it without missing old rows.(I rewrite old rows but it will take a long time). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add rows in between multiple rows, you need to shift all the rows below it down by one row, and create a new row: for example if you need to add another row in 5th position, and  the sheet contains 10 rows just shift 5 to 10 rows by one step down

```
    sheet.shiftRows(5, 10, 1);
```

and add new row in 5th position

```
    sheet.createRow(5);
```

You can use `shiftRows` to delete as well, in that case you just need to pass the third argument in minus. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21956362/624003) as well

**NOTE**: Delete first row carefully... In proper handling may corrupt your excel file.