# How to delete range of rows in Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

From Java, using Apache POI I just want to delete range of rows in my Excel sheet. For example: I want to delete row 45 to row 150. How to do that?

Comment: I am guessing that you can set the cells to empty string or null, but I would start off by creating a new Excel file and only adding rows 0 to 44. You can then delete the old file and use the file info from the old file to create a new file with the same name and location.

Comment: here is some discussen, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946958/how-to-remove-a-row-using-apache-poi