# How to delete an entire row from excel using Java Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to delete an entire row from excel,

I have tried `removeRow`:

```
XSSFRow rerow = sheet1.getRow(1);
sheet1.removeRow(rerow);
```

and `shiftRows`:

```
int rowIndex = 1;
int lastIntext = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
sheet1.shiftRows(rowIndex+1, lastIntext, -1);
```

But it is deleting only values in row not the entire row.

Answer (score 2):

Even i faced the same problems but figured after a couple of researches and found

There was a bug/or they might have changed the behavior in `<version>4.0.0</version> and <version>4.0.1</version>` of Apache Poi 
for

```
sheet1.shiftRows(rowIndex+1, lastIntext, -1);
```

Please use

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

And use your code much better way to remove you row like this

```
public static void removeRow(Sheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum) {
            sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
        }
        if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
            Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if (removingRow != null) {
                sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

And it worked for me.
May be they might update it in next api releases

Thank you if it would have helped you

Comment: where i want to write <dependency> and i have used that above code which u have mention that is not helpful

Comment: Use <dependency> your pom.xml if you are using maven. Or replace your POI and  poi-ooxml jar version to 3.17

Comment: Until you change the version of jar ,this code wont work

Comment: You can download jar from this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.17

Comment: I have tried including poi-3.17 jar file still entire row was not deleting

Comment: u can try 3.17 and 3.13 and u should update all poi jars Like poi and poi-ooxml
I have checked and it will work and use my function removeRow() and send the row index like  removeRow(sheet, 3); this.

Comment: And kindly remove 4.0.0 POI jars clean build your project to ensure that  dependencies are not reflecting

Comment: I have removed all 4.0.1 poi jars but i am getting this error Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: OOXML file structure broken/invalid - core document '/xl/workbook.xml' not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186956/discussion-between-priya-dharshan-and-kishan-c-s).